# Clean JSON column from bad data in Snowflake

Tags: json, json.net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in Snowflake with many columns, and one of those columns is JSON column called RECORD (check attached pic), so JSON column has multiple columns in it and some of these columns has bad data like ( // , * or \\ ) and I would like to create function in snowflake to clean up this JSON column from bad data, my JSON is below

```json
{
  "F000 //Start Date": "3/3/2016 21:04",
  "F001 End Date": "3/3/2016 23:20",
  "F002 *Response Type//": "IP Address",
  "F003 IP Address": "166.170.14.93",
  "F004 SurveyName\\": "6 Month",
}
```

[image]

Comment: I see the input - what's the exact desired output? Any query you have tried?

Comment: there is no plan for extract data from this JSON column, what the current task is to clean up this columns from any unwanted data like ( //, * or \\) using a function or SP in Snowflake

Comment: But what's the exact desired output? Any query you have tried?

Comment: The output will be create view on top of this JSON with exact column names, but need to clean the columns from any bad data like                                                             CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MULESOFT_DEV.SURVEY_RESULTS.TEST AS 
SELECT
RECORD:"F000 Start Date"::STRING as "Start Date", 
RECORD:"F001 End Date"::STRING as "End Date", 
RECORD:"F002 Response Type"::STRING as "Response Type", 
RECORD:"F003 IP Address"::STRING as "IP Address", 
RECORD:"F004 SurveyName"::STRING as "Survey Name",

FROM "MULESOFT_DEV"."SURVEY_RESULTS"."SURVEY_RESPONSES_HISTORICAL_DATA_BackUp"

Answer (score 0):

A simple way might be to implement a Javascript UDF that returns the cleaned up JSON, like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean(record variant)
  RETURNS variant
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS $$
  cleaned = {}
  for (const property in RECORD) {
    cleaned[property.replace(/\/\/|\\|\*/g, '')] = RECORD[property]
  }
  return cleaned
  $$;

with tbl as (select parse_json($1) record from values ('{
  "F000 //Start Date": "3/3/2016 21:04",
  "F001 End Date": "3/3/2016 23:20",
  "F002 *Response Type//": "IP Address",
  "F003 IP Address": "166.170.14.93",
  "F004 SurveyName\\\\": "6 Month",
}'))

select clean(record) from tbl;

{
  "F000 Start Date": "3/3/2016 21:04",
  "F001 End Date": "3/3/2016 23:20",
  "F002 Response Type": "IP Address",
  "F003 IP Address": "166.170.14.93",
  "F004 SurveyName": "6 Month"
}
```